# Importing image into powerpoint

Tags: images, microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-visio

I am using Microsoft Powerpoint 2010. When I import an image from visio or a pdf version of that image into powerpoint, the image gets some blurry.

Any solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Depending on how you import the image you might end up with a low-resolution pixel-based image

If I get you right, you want to input a high-quality version of something created in Visio into a PowerPoint slide.

In my oppinion the best way to achieve this is to export the image as `.emf` from Visio and use this in PP. If you do this, sometimes the image seems blurry while editing the PP slide, but will look nice if printed or if you do a full-screen presentation. I was not able to find out why this is.

BTW: if you just drag&drop a Visio 2010 file into PP 2010 you will end up with an EMF file being inserted. You can check this by opening the pptx file manually and looking into the `\ppt\media\` folder. (pptx files are normal zip-archives)

Comment: The emf method works.
Thank you.
Actually, i am making a large size poster using ppt.

Comment: Should you use non-vector grapics in your poster, keep in mind to set PP to save images in high-quality. This is quite hidden in the options, but look here: http://presentationsoft.about.com/od/PowerPoint-Pictures/ss/110305-powerpoint-picture-resolution.htm

Comment: BTW, i have two more images in PDF format. how can i insert them ?

Comment: This has several suggestions (from my PPT FAQ site) Import PDF content into PowerPoint
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00054_Import_PDF_content_into_PowerPoint.htm